# Scraping HTML using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have written a script using Beautiful Soup to scrape some HTML and do some stuff and produce HTML back. However, I am not convinced with my code and I am looking for some improvements.

Structure of my source HTML file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
...
<body>
...

<section id="article-section-1">
                <div id="article-section-1-icon" class="icon">
                    <img src="../images/introduction.jpg" />
                </div>  
                <div id="article-section-1-heading" 
                     class="heading">
                    Some Heading 1
                </div>
                <div id="article-section-1-content" 
                     class="content">   
                    This section can have p, img, or even div tags
                </div>
</section>

...
...

<section id="article-section-8">
                <div id="article-section-8-icon" class="icon">
                    <img src="../images/introduction.jpg" />
                </div>  
                <div id="article-section-8-heading" 
                     class="heading">
                    Some Heading
                </div>
                <div id="article-section-8-content" 
                     class="content">   
                    This section can have p, img, or even div tags
                </div>
</section>

...

</body>
</html>
```

My code:

```python
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(myhtml)
all_sections = soup.find_all('section',id=re.compile("article-section-[0-9]"))
for section in all_sections:
    heading = str(section.find_all('div',class_="heading")[0].text).strip()
    contents_list = section.find_all('div',class_="content")[0].contents
    content = ''
    for i in contents_list:
        if i != '\n':
            content = content+str(i)
    print '<html><body><h1>'+heading+'</h1><hr>'+content+'</body></html>'
```

My code works perfectly without any issues so far, however, I don't find it pythonic. I believe that it could be done in a much better/simpler way.

1. `Content_list` is a list which has items like `'\n'`. With a loop running over this list, I am removing it.  Is there any better way?
2. I am not interested in article icon, so I am ignoring it in my script.
3. I am using `strip` method to remove extra white spaces in the heading.  Is there any better way?
4. Other than new lines, the `div` element within content can have anything, even nested `div`s. So far, I have run my script over a few pages I have and it seems to work. Anything here I need to take care of?
5. Lastly, is there any better way to generate HTML files? Once I scraped data, I will work on generating HTML files. These files will have same structure (CSS, JavaScript, etc) and I have to do is put scraped data into it. Can the above method I used (build a string and put content and headings) be improved in any way?

I am not looking for full code in answers; just give me subtle hints or point me in some direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

regarding 1 you can:

```
new_content = [c for c in old_content if c != '\n']
```

or simply

```
new_content = old_content.replace('\n', '')
```

Regarding 5, if your are generating anything that is nontrivial, then it will pay off to learn some template engines like [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/). If that is too much, then you can make a simple template in text file and use [regex](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) or even `replace()` to substitute generic parts:

```
# template
<div class="some value">%FOO%</div>
<div class="some value">%BAR%</div>
```

and on the python side:

```
values = {"%FOO%": "the foos", "%BAR%": "the bars"} 
template = open('template').read()
for k, v in values.iteritems():
    template = template.replace(k, v)
print template
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `find` instead of `findAll` as `findAll` searches every element, thus taking more time.  If only the first element matters, using `find` can save a lot of time.