# Extract html content based on tags, specifically headers

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I want the function to take as an input json file containing html_body with its corresponding url and return list of tuples containing headers and their corresponding url (so could be tuple with one item as a list of the headers).

So far I have been able to do so, but I'm missing some headers and more over, I'm sure that this code can be improved.

Commented out possible extensions for `<h2>` headers extraction, and a different regex pattern I tried.

A taste of the source:

```
[["<body class=\" catalog-category-view categorypath-sale-html category-sale\">\n<script type=\"text/javascript\">\n//<![CDATA[\nif (typeof(Varien.searchForm) !== 'undefined') {\n    Varien.searchForm.prototype._selectAutocompleteItem = function(element) {\n        var link = element.down();\n        if (link && link.tagName == 'A') {\n            setLocation(link.href);\n        } else {\n            if (element.title){\n                this.field.value = element.title;\n            }\n            this.form.submit();\n        }\n    };\n    Varien.searchForm.prototype.initAutocomplete = function(url, destinationElement) {\n        new Ajax.Autocompleter(\n            this.field,\n            destinationElement,\n            url,\n            {\n                paramName: this.field.name,\n                method: 'get',\n                minChars: 2,\n                frequency: .3,\n                updateElement: this._selectAutocompleteItem.bind(this),\n                onShow : function(element, update) {\n                    if(!update.style.position || update.style.position=='absolute') {\n                        update.style.position = 'absolute';\n                        Position.clone(element, update, {\n                            setHeight: false,\n                            offsetTop: element.offsetHeight\n                        });\n                    }\n                    Effect.Appear(update,{duration:0});\n                }\n\n            }\n        );\n    };\n    Autocompleter.Base.prototype.markPrevious = function() {\n        if (this.index > 0) {\n            this.index--;\n        } else {\n            this.index = this.entryCount - 1;\n        }\n        var entry = this.getEntry(this.index);\n        if (entry.select('a').length === 0) {\n            this.markPrevious(); // Ignore items that don't have link\n        }\n    };\n    Autocompleter.Base.prototype.markNext = function() {\n        if (this.index < this.entryCount - 1) {\n
```

Code:

```
from pandas import DataFrame, Series
from tqdm import tqdm
import html5lib
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_headers_from_json(local_path):
"""
The function takes a json file with html_body and returns a list of headers.
It parses the headers, based on tags starting with 'h'.
It also parses urls and return them in a tuple: (headers, url)
"""
data = json.loads(open(local_path).read())
pattern = "h1" # | h2 | h3"   
# pattern = re.compile("^(?!.*(href)).*^h", re.IGNORECASE)
headers_urls = []
all_headers = []
for x in tqdm(data):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(x[0], 'html.parser')
    html_headers = soup.find_all(re.compile(pattern))
    all_headers.append(html_headers)
    url = x[1]
    tuple_title_url = all_headers, url
    headers_urls.append(tuple_title_url)
return headers_urls
```

PS - I checked the following links but couldn't find a great solution:
[HTML tag encoder](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/10809/html-tag-encoder)
[HTML parsing algorithm for extracting <a> tags](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/138003/html-parsing-algorithm-for-extracting-a-tags)
[Scraping HTML using Beautiful Soup](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/30992/scraping-html-using-beautiful-soup)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you are matching a single `h1` tag only, but, from what I understand, you want to catch all the "header" elements. There are multiple ways to do that.

One is with a regular expression:

```
headers = soup.find_all(re.compile(r"^h"))
```

Or, with a lambda function:

```
headers = soup.find_all(lambda tag: tag and tag.name.startswith("h"))
```

Or, with a list of explicitly specified tags:

```
headers = soup.find_all(['h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5'])
```

Note that in order to get the header texts, you would use `.get_text()` method:

```
[header.get_text() for header in headers]
```

---

**Other notes:**

- if every item returned from `tqdm(data)` consists of two items, you can *unpack* them in a `for` loop:

  ```
  for html, url in tqdm(data):
  ```

  Then, you can use `html` instead of `x[0]` and `url` instead of `x[1]`.
- if you are going to go with a regular expression approach to match the headers, you should *pre-compile the expression* - define it as a *constant*:

  ```
  HEADER_PATTERN = re.compile(r"^h")
  ```
- you can use `json.load()` to read JSON from a file directly, replace:

  ```
  data = json.loads(open(local_path).read())
  ```

  with:

  ```
  with open(local_path) as input_file:
      data = json.load(input_file)
  ```

**If performance matters:**

- you can use a faster JSON parser: [`ujson`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ujson) instead of `json`
- use `lxml` instead of `html.parser` as a `BeautifulSoup` underlying parser
- you can parse header elements only with [`SoupStrainer`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#parsing-only-part-of-a-document) ignoring all other elements - this should boost HTML parsing performance as well

**Improved code** (with some of the suggestions applied):

```
import re

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
from tqdm import tqdm
import ujson


HEADER_PATTERN = re.compile(r"^h")


def get_headers_from_json(local_path):
    """
    The function takes a json file with html_body and returns a list of headers.
    It parses the headers, based on tags starting with 'h'.
    It also parses urls and return them in a tuple: (headers, url)
    """
    with open(local_path) as input_file:
        data = ujson.load(input_file)

    parse_only = SoupStrainer(HEADER_PATTERN)
    return [
        ([header.get_text() for header in BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml', parse_only=parse_only)(HEADER_PATTERN)], url)
        for html, url in tqdm(data)
    ]
```

Comment: Thank you @alecxe , a couple of clarifications:

1. Wouldn't ur pattern get "href" as well? I suggest instead: r"^h[0-9]$"
2.  My code works fine without ".get_text" and I noticed that your's doesn't include it as well.
3. What are the benefits of turning the one line to read the JSON file into 2 lines?
4. Reg UJSON see: [link](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=9326499)

Cheers,

Comment: @oba2311 Thanks for the comment. 1. Yours regex is a bit more explicit, yeah, but `href` would not be matched since the expression is applied to *tag names* only. 2. `.get_text()` would only be needed if you need the text of the nodes (excluding the opening and closing tags).

Comment: @oba2311 ah, did not see your edit. 3. not a big deal, it is simply a bit clearer. Plus, we are following the best-practices and safely closing the file with a context manager. 4. I would suggest to measure performance of different json parsers on your specific use-case - your machine, your json input etc. Thanks.